# Replace all words from array in php

Tags: php, search, text

How can I find & highlight all words from array in text?

example:

```
$words = array('Test', 'I', 'tHiS', 'diFFerent');
```

Expecting result is:
Hi, **i**'m in **this** simple **test I**'d like to show you who we can replace **different** words.

Comment: What do you mean with "highlight"? Are you talking about bolding in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace("~(".implode("|" , array_map(function($a){
    return preg_quote($a,"~");
},$words)).")~i" , "<strong>$1</strong>" , $str);
```

you may try

```
$str = preg_replace("~(".implode("|" , array_map(function($a){
    return '\b'.preg_quote($a,"~").'\b';
},$words)).")~i" , "<strong>$1</strong>" , $str);
```

to specify that it should be *full* word

Comment: This works pretty good for english words, but, fails on Russian, especially on words with different case.

Comment: try to use `u` modifier with `i` one to compare as UTF-8

Comment: works better but I still have a problem with case-insensitive which is not working for russian, but works for english. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$words = array('Test', 'I', 'tHiS', 'diFFerent');
$str = "Hi, i'm in this simple test I'd like to show you who we can replace different words.";
$str = preg_replace("/(".implode("|" , $words).")/i" , "<b>$1</b>" , $str);
echo $str;
```

However, this will highlight all "I" in the string.